# Length of special characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Why is the length of `"\n\n\n"` 3? Is it because `\n` is a special character in JS?

```
var temp = "\n\n\n";
var length = temp.length; //Expected:6 Actual:3
```

Comment: `\n` is a line break. A line break is one character.

Comment: Typo. Now it's fixed.

Comment: Okay, I thought there might be more to it than that lol...cool thanks I'll close my question

Comment: Don't remove your question. Leave it here for others to stumble upon and learn from.

Comment: This question got me too as a beginner many years ago. The intuition is, most (if not all) escape characters occupy 1 char in length. The backslash is just a way to say "escape". Agree keep the question here for people to stumble upon and learn from.

Answer (score 3):

## Because `\n` is an [escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence).

The `\` (backslash) is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) that means that the immediately following character should be interpreted differently than it usually is. This is used in several programming languages (not just JavaScript) to represent a single character that can't be typed or would cause confusion in a string literal (for example, double or single quotes). In this case, the sequence `\n` represents a [*single "new line" character*](http://www.asciitable.com/), and you have three of them, so the length is three.

Comment: Technically, only ``\`` is the escape character. `\n` is an escape sequence (for this particular control character: the newline).